# $(A^{(k)})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ is unitary. Show $(A^{(\infty)})$ is unitary.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $(A^{(k)})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of unitary $n \times n$ matrices, such that $(A^{(\infty)})=(\lim\limits_{k \rightarrow \infty}
 (A^{(k)})_{i,j}$ exists for all indices.

Show $(A^{(\infty)})$ is unitary.

I am **not** looking for a solution, but rather I need a hint on what I am trying to show. So I can use that for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$ $\quad A$ is unitary. Ok, something like this ? :

Let $\gamma$ denote the inner product defined on the vector space.
$$ \gamma(A^{(\infty)}x,A^{(\infty)}y)=
\gamma((\lim\limits_{k \rightarrow \infty}
 (A^{(k)})_{i,j}x,(\lim\limits_{k \rightarrow \infty}
 (A^{(k)})_{i,j}y)
 $$ because the inner product is continuous 
$$ \lim\limits_{k \rightarrow \infty} \gamma(A^{(k)})_{i,j}x,(A^{(k)})_{i,j}y) $$
because $A$ is unitary for all indices $k\in \mathbb{N}$, it follows 
$$\lim\limits_{k \rightarrow \infty} \gamma(x,y)=\gamma(x,y) $$

It follows that $(A^{(\infty)})$ is unitary.

**Is this correct? If not, how could you approach this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes your argument is correct, although you should probably argue that $A^{(k)}x$ converges to $A^{(\infty)}x$ for all vectors $x$. But that isn't hard to do.

Alternatively, you could also argue that $A^{(\infty)}$ preserves norm. This isn't any harder or easier to do, but the proof will look a bit nicer since there's just one argument.